# Mimicking a calculator inputs and screen

Tags: tcolorbox

I want to mimic a calculator inputs and display with latex, after looking at several packages like `tipfr` and `ticollege` and finding them unsatisfactory to my needs I decided to do it myself with `tcolorbox`, and piecing together a few answers from here. Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[openany,10pt]{book}

\usepackage{newpxtext}

\usepackage[varg]{newpxmath} %font package

\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=0.75in,bindingoffset=0.5in]{geometry}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
    \colorlet{blackened}{black!90!white}
    \colorlet{blackish}{black!70!white}
    \colorlet{greyish}{black!60!white}
    \colorlet{whiteish}{white}
    \colorlet{orangeish}{yellow!90!red}
    \colorlet{greenish}{green!16!gray}
    \colorlet{redish}{red!80!black}

\tcbset{calbackground/.style={
    enhanced, 
    leftright skip=0.25cm,beforeafter skip=0pt,
    toptitle=0mm,bottomtitle=0mm,
    right=2mm,left=2mm, 
    top=1pt,
    bottom=0.25cm,
    boxsep=0pt,
    boxrule=0mm, 
    sharp corners,
    sidebyside,
    sidebyside gap=2mm,
    lefthand ratio=0.6,
    bicolor,
    colback=black!10!white, 
    colbacklower=greenish,
    colframe=white, 
    autoparskip,
    }}

\newtcbtheorem[no counter]{calx}{Calculator}{calbackground}{cax}

\newtcbox{\KY}[1][]{
    enhanced,
    on line,
    arc=2pt,outer arc=2pt,
    boxrule=0pt,bottomrule=0.25mm,rightrule=0.2mm,
    boxsep=0pt,left=0pt,right=0pt,top=1pt,bottom=1pt,
    interior style={top color=blackish,bottom color=blackened},
    colframe=greyish,
    width=2.5em,
    tcbox width=forced center,
    equal height group=K,
    valign=center,
    fontupper=\footnotesize\sffamily,
    coltext=orangeish,}
%   coltitle=redish,colbacktitle=white,fonttitle=\footnotesize\sffamily,squeezed title=#1,center title,}

\newtcbox{\KN}{
    enhanced,
    on line,
    arc=2pt,outer arc=2pt,
    boxrule=0pt,bottomrule=0.25mm,rightrule=0.2mm,
    boxsep=0pt,left=0pt,right=0pt,top=1pt,bottom=1pt,
    interior style={top color=blackish,bottom color=blackened},
    colframe=greyish,
    width=1.5em,
    tcbox width=forced center,
    equal height group=K,
    valign=center,
    fontupper=\footnotesize\sffamily,
    coltext=whiteish,}

\usepackage{lcd}
    \LCDcolors{black}{greenish}
    \DefineLCDchar{sq}{11100001000100011100000000000000000}
    \DefineLCDchar{tm}{00000100010101000100010101000100000}
    \DefineLCDchar{dv}{00000001000000011111000000010000000}
    \DefineLCDchar{mu}{00011000011110100001000000000000000}
    \DefineLCDchar{sc}{11011010011001000000000000000000000}

\DeclareMathOperator{\ee}{\textrm{e}}

\usepackage{MnSymbol} %boxes
\usepackage{xfrac} %sfrac
\usepackage{lipsum} %for textwidth comparison
    \setlipsumdefault{1-2}

\begin{document}

\begin{calx}{}{} 
\KY{$($}\KN{3}\KY{$x^2$}\KN{-}\KN{4}\KY{$x^2$}\KN{-}\KN{6}\KY{$x^2$}\KY{$)$}\KN{$=$}
\tcblower
{\Large\textLCD[0]{20}|(3{sq}-4{sq}-6{sq})|}
{\LARGE\textLCD[0]{16}|             -43|}
\end{calx}
%
\begin{calx}{}{} 
\KN{$\div$}\KY{$($}\KY{$(-)$}\KN{2}\KN{$\times$}\KN{4}\KN{$\times$}\KN{6}\KY{$)$}\KN{$=$}
\tcblower
{\Large\textLCD[0]{20}|ANS{dv}(-2{tm}4{tm}6)|}
{\LARGE\textLCD[0]{16}|    0.8958333333|}
\end{calx}
%
\begin{calx}{}{} 
\KY{$\cos^{-1}$}\KY{ANS}\KN{$=$}
\tcblower
{\Large\textLCD[0]{20}|cos{mu}(ANS|}
{\LARGE\textLCD[0]{16}|     26.38432975|}
\end{calx}
%
\begin{calx}{}{} 
\KY{$\circ\,\prime\,\prime\prime$}
\tcblower
{\Large\textLCD[0]{20}|cos{mu}(ANS|}
{\LARGE\textLCD[0]{16}|     26°23'3.59{sc} |}
\end{calx}

\lipsum

\KY{$x^2$}%
\KY{$x^3$}%
\KY{$x^{-1}$}%
\KY{$x^{\filledsquare}$}%
\KY{$\sqrt{\filledmedsquare}$}%
\KY{$\sqrt[3]{\filledmedsquare}$}%
\KY{$\sqrt[\filledsquare]{\medsquare}$}\\

\KY{$\ln$}%
\KY{$\log$}%
\KY{$\log_{\filledsquare}\medsquare$}%
\KY{$10^{\filledsquare}$}%
\KY{$\ee^{\filledsquare}$}\\

\KY{$(-)$}%
\KY{$\frac{\filledmedsquare}{\medsquare}$}%
\KY{$\sfrac{\filledmedsquare}{\medsquare}$}%
\KY{$\tfrac{\filledmedsquare}{\medsquare}$}\\

\KY{$\circ\,\prime\,\prime\prime$}%
\KY{$\sin$}%
\KY{$\sin^{-1}$}%
\KY{$\cos$}%
\KY{$\cos^{-1}$}%
\KY{$\tan$}%
\KY{$\tan^{-1}$}\\

\KY{$($}%
\KY{$)$}%
\KN{$\times$}%
\KN{$\div$}%
\KN{$+$}%
\KN{$-$}%
\KN{$=$}\\

\KN{$1$}%
\KN{$2$}%
\KN{$3$}%
\KN{$4$}%
\KN{$5$}%
\KN{$6$}%
\KN{$7$}%
\KN{$8$}%
\KN{$9$}%
\KN{$0$}\\

\KN{1}%
\KN{2}%
\KN{3}%
\KN{4}%
\KN{5}%
\KN{6}%
\KN{7}%
\KN{8}%
\KN{9}%
\KN{0}\\

\end{document}
```

[image]

This looks and works almost exactly the way I need it to, but I've a few difficulties:

1) The keys don't all align on the same line

2) The text inside different keys doesn't align on the same line

3) I can't figure out how to add a second function over a key, like `sin^{-1}` over the `sin` key, while also solving the first two problems.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can add some modifications to the answer of Rmano. The `\strut` or something similar can be put directly into the definition of `\KY` and `\KN` using the `before upper` option, e.g.

```
before upper=\vrule width 0pt height 2ex depth 1ex\relax,
```

I noticed that you used `\KY{$...$}` in most cases. The `$` signs also can be put into the definition of `\KY` and `\KN`. I made a copy of `\KY` as `\KYM` which is

```
\newtcbox{\KYm}[1][]{
    enhanced,
    on line,
    arc=2pt,outer arc=2pt,
    boxrule=0pt,bottomrule=0.25mm,rightrule=0.2mm,
    boxsep=0pt,left=0pt,right=0pt,top=1pt,bottom=1pt,
    interior style={top color=blackish,bottom color=blackened},
    colframe=greyish,
    width=2.5em,
    tcbox width=forced center,
    equal height group=K,
    valign=center,
    fontupper=\footnotesize\sffamily,
    coltext=orangeish,
    before upper=\vrule width 0pt height 2ex depth 1ex\relax$,
    after upper=$,
    }
```

Now, the application is `\KYm{...}` to set something in mathematical mode.

[image]

The full code is:

```
\documentclass[openany,10pt]{book}

\usepackage{newpxtext}

\usepackage[varg]{newpxmath} %font package

\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=0.75in,bindingoffset=0.5in]{geometry}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
    \colorlet{blackened}{black!90!white}
    \colorlet{blackish}{black!70!white}
    \colorlet{greyish}{black!60!white}
    \colorlet{whiteish}{white}
    \colorlet{orangeish}{yellow!90!red}
    \colorlet{greenish}{green!16!gray}
    \colorlet{redish}{red!80!black}

\tcbset{calbackground/.style={
    enhanced,
    leftright skip=0.25cm,beforeafter skip=0pt,
    toptitle=0mm,bottomtitle=0mm,
    right=2mm,left=2mm,
    top=1pt,
    bottom=0.25cm,
    boxsep=0pt,
    boxrule=0mm,
    sharp corners,
    sidebyside,
    sidebyside gap=2mm,
    lefthand ratio=0.6,
    bicolor,
    colback=black!10!white,
    colbacklower=greenish,
    colframe=white,
    autoparskip,
    }}

\newtcbtheorem[no counter]{calx}{Calculator}{calbackground}{cax}

\newtcbox{\KY}[1][]{
    enhanced,
    on line,
    arc=2pt,outer arc=2pt,
    boxrule=0pt,bottomrule=0.25mm,rightrule=0.2mm,
    boxsep=0pt,left=0pt,right=0pt,top=1pt,bottom=1pt,
    interior style={top color=blackish,bottom color=blackened},
    colframe=greyish,
    width=2.5em,
    tcbox width=forced center,
    equal height group=K,
    valign=center,
    fontupper=\footnotesize\sffamily,
    coltext=orangeish,
    before upper=\vrule width 0pt height 2ex depth 1ex\relax,
    }

\newtcbox{\KYm}[1][]{
    enhanced,
    on line,
    arc=2pt,outer arc=2pt,
    boxrule=0pt,bottomrule=0.25mm,rightrule=0.2mm,
    boxsep=0pt,left=0pt,right=0pt,top=1pt,bottom=1pt,
    interior style={top color=blackish,bottom color=blackened},
    colframe=greyish,
    width=2.5em,
    tcbox width=forced center,
    equal height group=K,
    valign=center,
    fontupper=\footnotesize\sffamily,
    coltext=orangeish,
    before upper=\vrule width 0pt height 2ex depth 1ex\relax$,
    after upper=$,
    }

\newtcbox{\KN}{
    enhanced,
    on line,
    arc=2pt,outer arc=2pt,
    boxrule=0pt,bottomrule=0.25mm,rightrule=0.2mm,
    boxsep=0pt,left=0pt,right=0pt,top=1pt,bottom=1pt,
    interior style={top color=blackish,bottom color=blackened},
    colframe=greyish,
    width=1.5em,
    tcbox width=forced center,
    equal height group=K,
    valign=center,
    fontupper=\footnotesize\sffamily,
    coltext=whiteish,
    before upper=\vrule width 0pt height 2ex depth 1ex\relax,
    }

\usepackage{lcd}
    \LCDcolors{black}{greenish}
    \DefineLCDchar{sq}{11100001000100011100000000000000000}
    \DefineLCDchar{tm}{00000100010101000100010101000100000}
    \DefineLCDchar{dv}{00000001000000011111000000010000000}
    \DefineLCDchar{mu}{00011000011110100001000000000000000}
    \DefineLCDchar{sc}{11011010011001000000000000000000000}

\DeclareMathOperator{\ee}{\textrm{e}}

\usepackage{MnSymbol} %boxes
\usepackage{xfrac} %sfrac
\usepackage{lipsum} %for textwidth comparison
    \setlipsumdefault{1-2}

\begin{document}

\begin{calx}{}{}
\KY{$($}\KN{3}\KY{$x^2$}\KN{-}\KN{4}\KY{$x^2$}\KN{-}\KN{6}\KY{$x^2$}\KY{$)$}\KN{$=$}
\tcblower
{\Large\textLCD[0]{20}|(3{sq}-4{sq}-6{sq})|}
{\LARGE\textLCD[0]{16}|             -43|}
\end{calx}
%
\begin{calx}{}{}
\KN{$\div$}\KY{$($}\KY{$(-)$}\KN{2}\KN{$\times$}\KN{4}\KN{$\times$}\KN{6}\KY{$)$}\KN{$=$}
\tcblower
{\Large\textLCD[0]{20}|ANS{dv}(-2{tm}4{tm}6)|}
{\LARGE\textLCD[0]{16}|    0.8958333333|}
\end{calx}
%
\begin{calx}{}{}
\KY{$\cos^{-1}$}\KY{ANS}\KN{$=$}
\tcblower
{\Large\textLCD[0]{20}|cos{mu}(ANS|}
{\LARGE\textLCD[0]{16}|     26.38432975|}
\end{calx}
%
\begin{calx}{}{}
\KY{$\circ\,\prime\,\prime\prime$}
\tcblower
{\Large\textLCD[0]{20}|cos{mu}(ANS|}
{\LARGE\textLCD[0]{16}|     26°23'3.59{sc} |}
\end{calx}

\lipsum

\KYm{x^2}%
\KYm{x^3}%
\KYm{x^{-1}}%
\KYm{x^{\filledsquare}}%
\KYm{\sqrt{\filledmedsquare}}%
\KYm{\sqrt[3]{\filledmedsquare}}%
\KYm{\sqrt[\filledsquare]{\medsquare}}\\

\KY{$\ln$}%
\KY{$\log$}%
\KY{$\log_{\filledsquare}\medsquare$}%
\KY{$10^{\filledsquare}$}%
\KY{$\ee^{\filledsquare}$}\\

\KY{$(-)$}%
\KY{$\frac{\filledmedsquare}{\medsquare}$}%
\KY{$\sfrac{\filledmedsquare}{\medsquare}$}%
\KY{$\tfrac{\filledmedsquare}{\medsquare}$}\\

\KY{$\circ\,\prime\,\prime\prime$}%
\KY{$\sin$}%
\KY{$\sin^{-1}$}%
\KY{$\cos$}%
\KY{$\cos^{-1}$}%
\KY{$\tan$}%
\KY{$\tan^{-1}$}\\

\KY{$($}%
\KY{$)$}%
\KN{$\times$}%
\KN{$\div$}%
\KN{$+$}%
\KN{$-$}%
\KN{$=$}\\

\KN{$1$}%
\KN{$2$}%
\KN{$3$}%
\KN{$4$}%
\KN{$5$}%
\KN{$6$}%
\KN{$7$}%
\KN{$8$}%
\KN{$9$}%
\KN{$0$}\\

\KN{1}%
\KN{2}%
\KN{3}%
\KN{4}%
\KN{5}%
\KN{6}%
\KN{7}%
\KN{8}%
\KN{9}%
\KN{0}\\

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, this actually looks slightly better in my larger document than the previous answer. I've implemented the $ symbols in both of my definitions, in my MWE I was still testing which looked better.

Answer (score 6):

I have solved the first two by using:

```
\let\KYo\KY
\let\KNo\KN
\renewcommand{\KY}[1]{\KYo{\makebox[1em][c]{\strut #1}}}
\renewcommand{\KN}[1]{\KNo{\makebox[1em][c]{\strut #1}}}
```

Just before the `\begin{document}` (to show the idea in a clear way and to avoid repeating all the code here...).

The idea is using a fixed width box and setting the height with a `\strut`. (You can have it higher using something like `\vrule width 0pt height 3ex depth 1ex \relax` instead of the `\strut`). Like this:

[image: Output ith \strut]

Or with the rule:

[image: Output with 3ex height and 1ex depth rule]

For the inverse thing, I would use the same trick using the [stack engine package](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/stackengine?lang=en), and a rule in front to set the height.

(BTW I had to remove line 113 of you MWE because it didn't compile (extra `\else` or something like that). Also it needs the most modern versions of a lot of packages).

Comment: I will have to look into the stack engine package, but your answer solves my first two problems very well, thank you.

About line 113: I have no idea what's going on, apparently the LCD package has difficulty compiling what it calls "multi-letter characters" if they appear at the end of their display syntax, such as my user defined {sc} character. 

I solved this after several attempts by putting a space after such a character, and it compiles for me but I have no idea why it works, or why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: Another last minute question, what did you mean by "Also it needs the most modern versions of a lot of packages"?

Comment: I have a stock LaTeX from Ubuntu 14.04 and I had to download the newest `tcolorbox` and `lcd` package to compile it... :-) --- no problem, really. My LaTeX is a bit outdated.

Comment: It must be said that this looks awesome.