# tcolorbox - equal height, but positioned as if not!

Tags: tcolorbox

I want to use `tcolorbox` to create `on line` (inline) boxes of equal height, using `equal height group`. But the boxes are positioned at different heights.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside, 12pt, parskip=half]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{common/.style={
    enhanced, size=small, nobeforeafter, on line, drop fuzzy shadow
  }
}
\newtcbox{\databoxcenter}[1]{
  common, leftrule=0pt, rightrule=0pt, equal height group=#1
}
\newtcbox{\databoxleft}[1]{
  common, rightrule=0pt, equal height group=#1
}
\newtcbox{\databoxright}[1]{
  common, leftrule=0pt, equal height group=#1
}

\begin{document}

The following boxes are positioned as if \texttt{equal height group} is not in effect:

\databoxleft{addr}{2/17,} \databoxcenter{addr}{Hamlet 5,} \databoxright{addr}{China}. The heights do seem equal, though.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way is to adjust the `baseline` value, i.e. `baseline=2mm` seems to be an appropriate value.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside, 12pt, parskip=half]{scrartcl}


\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{common/.style={
    box align=base,
    enhanced jigsaw, size=small,on line,baseline=2mm,drop fuzzy shadow
  }
}
\newtcbox{\databoxcenter}[1]{
  common,leftrule=0pt, rightrule=0pt, equal height group=#1
}

\newtcbox{\databoxleft}[1]{
  common, rightrule=0pt, equal height group=#1
}

\newtcbox{\databoxright}[1]{
  common, leftrule=0pt, equal height group=#1
}

\begin{document}

The following boxes are positioned as if \texttt{equal height group} is not in effect:

\databoxleft{addr}{2/17,} \databoxcenter{addr}{Hamlet,5} \databoxright{addr}{China}. The heights do seem equal, though.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Fantastic, simple. Tells me I should respect the world of typesetting as a formal domain, which is nothing less than the world of front-end programming (am a programmer). I feel your vibe; I use Emacs too!

Comment: @JonWong: Using a computer for typesetting it is programming in the long end... either by using the knowledge of others are applying own ideas...

Answer (score 3):

Another solution could be to force equal height and depth for all boxes. I've done adding `before upper=\strut` in `common` style definition.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside, 12pt, parskip=half]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{common/.style={
    enhanced, size=small, nobeforeafter, on line, drop fuzzy shadow,
    before upper=\strut
  }
}
\newtcbox{\databoxcenter}[1]{
  common, leftrule=0pt, rightrule=0pt, equal height group=#1
}
\newtcbox{\databoxleft}[1]{
  common, rightrule=0pt, equal height group=#1
}
\newtcbox{\databoxright}[1]{
  common, leftrule=0pt, equal height group=#1
}

\begin{document}

The following boxes are positioned as if \texttt{equal height group} is not in effect:

\databoxleft{addr}{2/17,} \databoxcenter{addr}{Hamlet 5,} \databoxright{addr}{China}. The heights do seem equal, though.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @lgnasi Nice solution. Similar to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/290321/mimicking-a-calculator-inputs-and-screen , which I also used as a hack before I found the answer to this question. But it defeats my option `size=small`.

Comment: @JonWong To compensate box size increase due to `\strut`, you can add `boxsep=0pt` after `size=small`.